# How to redirect a text in the textbox to google search

Tags: c#, wpf, google-search

I am creating a web browser application in wpf. I want to take the text from url textbox and perform a google search using the Web browser control.It should be in the same way as google chrome does that.How to achieve that?
Let me Update this with the code that i have written.

```
private void textBox1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        string toBeSearched = textBox1.Text;
        string GS = "http://google.com/search?q=";
        if ((e.Key == Key.Enter) && (e.KeyboardDevice.Modifiers == ModifierKeys.Control))
        {
            MessageBox.Show(toBeSearched);
            string[] parts = toBeSearched.Split(' ');
            foreach (string part in parts)
            {
                GS = GS + part+"+";

            }
            GS=GS.Remove(GS.Length - 1);
            MessageBox.Show(GS);
        }
    }
```

Here i am just creating a query string.is there any other easier method instead of creating a querystring?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. What have you tried so far ?

Comment: please show some source code... what have you tried ? what is not working ?

Comment: `private void urlTextBox_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)

Comment: @gaurav9021 - Using the Google Custom Search API would be a start.  **A single line of code is not a valid attempt.**

Comment: sorry,that was a typing error.I was about to update the question itsel.sorry.:-)

Comment: There is a **error** in your logic in the for-loop as well.

Please use this as follows.

string searchText = string.Empty;

foreach (string part in parts)
{
   searchText += part + "+";
}

GS += searchText;